# Using a standard toolbar or ios navigation bar icon

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbaritem

I see the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html

But is there anyway to get the icon by itself? Where is an example of this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't get bar icons from iOS. But, there are plenty open source exact look alike icon packs on the internet, just search on google. Good Luck!

Comment: What do you mean you can't get them? They don't allow you to use their standard set.

Comment: From Apple: Bar Icons

iOS provides a lot of small icons—representing common tasks and types of content—for use in tab bars, toolbars, and navigation bars. It’s a good idea to use the built-in icons as much as possible because users already know what they mean.

Comment: Yes, you can use them, just only on system bars like `UINavigationBar`, `UIToolbar`, etc with only `UIBarButtonItem`. Hope, this is helpful for you to understand my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIBarButtonSystemItem which has the predefined icons.

They are located here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem